# How to find joint PDF of Z and Y where Z = X + Y

Tags: statistics

Let there be two random variables X and Y. A third random variable Z is defined as Z = X + Y. Suppose we are given $f_{XY}$ (the joint probability density function of X and Y).

How do we calculate $f_{ZY}$ (the joint probability density function of Z and Y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starndard idea in this type of exercise is to start by fiding the cdf of $(Z,Y)$:
\begin{align*}
 P(Z \leq z_0, Y \leq y_0)
 &= P(X + Y \leq z_0, Y \leq y_0) \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{y_0}\int_{-\infty}^{z_0-y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy
\end{align*}
Conclude that
\begin{align*}
 f_{Z,Y}(z_0,y_0) 
 &= \frac{\partial^2 P(Z \leq z_0, Y \leq y_0)}{\partial z_0 \partial y_0} \\
 &= f_{X,Y}(z_0-y_0,y_0)
\end{align*}